# Does Hanuman Chalisa really compute the distance between Earth and Sun?

Tags: vedas, hanuman, science

Yuga means Divine Time so it's SI Unit would be Seconds.
Sastra Yojana means Distance.
Now, Distance x Time =/= Distance.

So, is this phrase correct or not?

Comment: Yes it is correct although might I add that this number deviates from what science has detected?

Comment: H. F:O. D. G:L. F.H. RMSY. 

Comment: .️♥️☮️.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, absolutely Hanuman Chalisa actually tells us the distance between the Sun and the Earth. But the actual scientific formula is Speed (S) = Distance (D) ÷ Time (T).

According to Records, For the first time in 1672, Jean Richer and Giovanni Domenico Cassini measured the distance between Earth and Sun as 22,000 times of Earth Radii.( Earth’s Radius is 6,371 Kms).

i.e 22000 * 6371 kms = 140,162,000 kms (140 Million Kms).

According to morden scientists of NASA, the distance between the Sun and the Earth is **around 15 crore kilometers.**

According to Modren Astronomy and Science , we know that the earth’s orbit around the sun is not a circle and is slightly elliptical. Therefore, the distance between the earth and the sun varies throughout the year.

At its nearest point on the ellipse that is the earth’s orbit around the sun, the earth is 91,445,000 miles (147,166,462 kms) from the sun. This point in the earth’s orbit is known as Periapsis (perihelion) and it occurs around January 3.

The earth is farthest away from the sun around July 3 when it is 94,555,000 miles (152,171,522 km) from the sun. This point in the earth’s orbit is called Apoapsis (aphelion). The average distance from the earth to the sun is 92,955,807 miles (149,597,870.691 km).

As Tuslidas Goswami ji (born 15th century), in Shree Hanuman Chalisa mentioned , the Distance between the Sun and the Earth, is same as the morden scientists had calculated. check the maths below:

Two lines of Hindu Prayer ” Hanuman Chalisa” computes this distance with great simplicity.

> **जुग सहस्त्र जोजन पर भानू।**
>
> लील्यो ताहि मधुर फल जानू।।18 l I

This means that Sun (भानु) is at a distance of  Juug Sahastra Yojans (जुग सहस्त्र योजन- Distance Unit in Sanskrit and Hindi).:

According to following conversion practices that are in use as per Hindu Vedic Literature.:->

जुग( युग / yuga) = 12000

एक सहस्त्र = 1000

एक जोजन (योजन / yojana) = 8 मील (miles)

भानु = सूर्य (sun)

युग x सहस्त्र x योजन = पर भानु यानि सूर्य की दूरी (the distance of the sun {from the earth})

12000 x 1000 x 8 मील = 96000000 मील

एक मील = 1.6 किमी / km

96000000 x 1.6 = **153600000 किमी (km).**

For more info look into [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-meaning-of-line-yug-shahstra-yojan-par-bhanu-which-is-taken-from-hanuman-chalisa), [this](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/k-4/features/F_Measuring_the_Distance_Student_Pages.html) and [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.wordzz.com/distance-sun-earth-mentioned-hanuman-chalisa-ancient-prayer/%3famp) sites.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133082/discussion-on-answer-by-savdy-does-hanuman-chalisa-really-compute-the-distance-b).